# How to initialize parent using member of child?

Tags: c++, inheritance, initialization

I have a class that I need to initialize:

```
//Parent.h
class Parent {
public:
    Parent(Image image);
private:
    const Image parentImage;
}

//Parent.cpp
Parent::Parent(Image image) : parentImage(image) {}

//Child.h

#import "Parent.h"

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child(int c);
private:
    Camera childCamera;
}

//Child.cpp
Child::Child(int c) : Parent(this->childCamera.getImage()), childCamera(c) {}
```

The `Camera` needs to be initialized before images can be retrieved from it. The `Parent` stores an image from the camera, which is `const`, the child stores the `Camera`. How can I create a `Child`? I can't change `Parent`, as there are other subclasses that initialize `Parent` in other ways. I can change `Child`, but `Camera` can't be copied, and the `Child` does need to store the `Camera`.

EDIT: I could add constructors to `Parent`, if that is the cleanest solution.

Comment: what is `this->childDataSource.getImage()`? Your code shows no dependency between `childCamera` and `Parent`

Comment: Sorry, should be `this->childCamera.getImage()`. The real situation has many more members and so on, I made an error when simplifying.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member

Answer (score 1):

Given all the design constraints you've listed, one reasonable solution would be to construct a Camera externally to the Child and then pass it into the Child's constructor. The Child would then take ownership of it.

So the class could be written like:

```
class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child(Camera* camera);
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Camera> childCamera;
}

//Child.cpp
Child::Child(Camera* camera) 
    : Parent(camera->getImage()), childCamera(camera) 
{}
```

And then used as:

```
Camera* camera = new Camera;
Child child(camera);
```

Comment: This would be better if the `Child` constructor took a `unique_ptr<Camera>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.

According to the standard (12.6.2/10) the order of initialisation is:

> — (...)
>
> — Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration
>   order as they appear in the base-specifier-list (regardless of the
>   order of the mem-initializers).
>
> — Then, non-static data members are
>   initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition
>   (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>
> — Finally,
>   the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed.

So in your `Child` constructor mem-initialization list, for the `Parent` initializer you **can't use anything that relies on `Child` member variables** because these are unitialized at that moment.

You could however use arguments of the Child constructor, for example:

```
Child::Child(int c) : Parent(c.getImage()), childCamera(c) {}
```

provided of course that every copy of a Camera object would return the same image as the original object.

Another alternative could be to use multiple inheritance from an auxiliary class (to use the second dash of the standard quote above).  But this i smore tricky and anyway would also require copy of camera object.

Answer (score 0):

no you can't. you can't use anything that relies on Child for Parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Base From Member idiom to achieve this. Basically you create an intermediate holder class/struct to hold the variable that used to be in Base Class and then you inherit the child class first from the holder class and then the Base class. With that method, you can initialize a parent

When you run below code, you will see that in the problematic case, Base Class doesn't get the intended value when it is initialized. But in the solution, it is initialized as expected. Let me know if this works for you.

```
#include "fmt/core.h"

struct TempStruct
{
    explicit TempStruct(int temp) : tempI_(temp)
    {
        fmt::print("TempStruct {} \n", tempI_);
    }

    int tempI_{33};
};

class BaseClass
{
  public:
    explicit BaseClass(TempStruct* pTemp)
    {
        fmt::print("BaseClass tempstruct {}\n", pTemp->tempI_);
    }
};

class ChildClass : public BaseClass
{
  public:
    // Below code doesn't work as expected. BaseClass initilizers first and then
    // TempStruct. So BaseClass doesn't get TempStruct with 5. Field
    // 'tempStruct_' will be initialized after base 'BaseClass' [-Wreorder-ctor]
    ChildClass() : tempStruct_{5}, BaseClass(&tempStruct_)
    {
    }

  private:
    // Member initialize tempStruct_ to 10;
    TempStruct tempStruct_{10};
};

// Solution

struct TempStructHolder
{
    TempStructHolder(int i) : tempStruct_{i}
    {
    }

    TempStruct tempStruct_{0};
};

class SolutionChildClass : public TempStructHolder, public BaseClass
{
  public:
    SolutionChildClass() : TempStructHolder(39), BaseClass(&tempStruct_)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    fmt::print("Problem \n");

    [[maybe_unused]] const ChildClass c;

    fmt::print("Solutin \n");

    [[maybe_unused]] const SolutionChildClass sc;
}
```